# How do i select this text in Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

[image: this is the html]

I need to get the text in the red circle

```
doc.select("p#latest-buy").text()
```

I've tried doing this but it appears to be empty

Comment: Which URL are you trying to scrape?

Comment: Is this it: https://lirarate.org/ ?

Comment: Looks like the site uses AJAX.

Comment: @JanezKuhar Yes that is the url, i will look into HtmlUnit thanks a lot